# discord.js | Couldn't resolve the user ID to unban

Tags: discord.js

Hello I'm trying to make a discord bot to unban someone but it gives me this error:

```js
Unhandled promise rejection: Error [BAN_RESOLVE_ID]: Couldn't resolve the user ID to unban.
    at GuildMemberManager.unban (C:\Users\Jakub Sokol\Documents\Coding\Discord Bots\Smiley\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberManager.js:210:36)
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\Jakub Sokol\Documents\Coding\Discord Bots\Smiley\commands\unban.js:17:35)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jakub Sokol\Documents\Coding\Discord Bots\Smiley\index.js:70:11)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Jakub Sokol\Documents\Coding\Discord Bots\Smiley\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\Jakub Sokol\Documents\Coding\Discord Bots\Smiley\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Jakub Sokol\Documents\Coding\Discord Bots\Smiley\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Jakub Sokol\Documents\Coding\Discord Bots\Smiley\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Jakub Sokol\Documents\Coding\Discord Bots\Smiley\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Jakub Sokol\Documents\Coding\Discord Bots\Smiley\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'BAN_RESOLVE_ID'
}
```

Here is my code on it:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
    name: 'unban',
    description: "Ping!",
    async execute(client, message, args) {
        if(!message.member.hasPermission(['BAN_MEMBERS', 'ADMINISTRATOR'])) return message.channel.send("You don't have permission to use that command!");
        if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission(['BAN_MEMBERS', 'ADMINISTRATOR'])) return message.channel.send("I don't have permissions to unban members!")
        
        let bannedMember = parseInt(args[0]);
            if(isNaN(bannedMember)) return message.channel.send("You need to give me a valid ID!");

        let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
            if(!reason) return reason = "No reason given.";
        
        message.delete()
        try {
            message.guild.members.unban(bannedMember, reason);
            message.channel.send(`Succesfully unbanned ${bannedMember}!`)
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }

    }
}
```

And here is what I typed: `/unban 262258367903301632 test` I don't really know what is wrong with it and I couldn't find any answers to this :/

Answer (score 1):

The error says he can't find a user with that identification. Create a secondary account, ban the account and from this command. If you want to check if this user is banned, you can try to check if he is on your server using

```
if (!message.guild.members.get(bannedMember)) return message.reply("This user is not banned!")
```

I don't know how to check if it's really banned, but this can help you now

(I'm using a translator)